# Padding the sentences is consuming huge memory

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I prepared a lstm model using tensorflow which has a `max_sequence_length` of 5000 and I'm padding the small sentences with 0's. I then deployed and tested the model with multiple calls at a time. I then encountered a memory error because the `max_sequence_length` is consuming a lot of memory.

Is there is any alternative to writing the model more efficiently using some thing as an alternative to padding?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tried alternatives like storing it in `csr` matrices in scipy, you can move away from padding to avoid memory issues by declaring your `batch_size=1` and may be create batches using a `groupby` for equal length sequences. If you are using keras, then please check **Masking**.